# Should Validation Change Data?

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I have some services that we use for validation.  They contain a mix of simple data validation but also some more complex business logic.  Some of these validation calls also 'clean up' the data so that it fits our standard.  This seems like it should be done elsewhere (single responsibility).

My understanding of validating data is, it simply answers a yes/no question (is it valid) and possibly returning some validation message.  So it will return a bool or a validation error of some type.

If we want to format the data prior to saving or processing we should have another layer of code that cleans up for formats the data.

Take a look at the below example.  We have two methods that both check the length of the string.  The second one additionally converts it to upper if it is the correct length.  So it alters the string as part of its process.

Question:  The core question I have is, when talking about validation, should we be concerned with cleaning up/formatting data?  In other words, should validation alter data?

```
public class ValidationService
{
    public bool ValidateText(string text)
    {
        bool rtn = false;

        if (IsStringCorrectLength(text))
        {
            rtn = true;
        }

        return rtn;
    }

    public bool ValidateTextAndFormat(string text)
    {
        bool rtn = false;

        if (IsStringCorrectLength(text))
        {
            text = text.ToUpper();
            rtn = true;
        }

        return rtn;
    }

    private bool IsStringCorrectLength(string text)
    {
        bool rtn = false;
        if (text.Length < 11)
        {
            rtn = true;
        }

        return rtn;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the code works fine, I'd be asking this question on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com): We do "help, it doesn't work", they do "OK, it *works*, but...". We'd call this "opinion based". That said, your sense of things is correct, in my opinion (see Orel's answer), and I don't think you'll get a whole lot of disagreement. However, in production code, we often keep ugly code for years. If it it works perfectly and isn't causing any problems elsewhere, fixing it is a low priority. Good question, wrong venue.

Comment: From my experience "NO".

Validation & Data Manipulation is two different topics. Each should be handle properly in the designated services. Otherwise, you will have a tightly coupled components, very resistant to changes.

Comment: More suitable for the [ux.se] site.

Comment: Yeah, sorry will look at moving this over to Software Engineering.  Don't really post a lot of stuff on here.  I should make myself more familiar with the rules.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you "smelled" this should be in separate concerns.

1. Validation Concern
2. Manipulation/Normalization Concern

This will prevent complexity and "weird" side effect (changing the data), when calling Validation, and it ensures validation only concern about checking the validation and not about "how" to format data.

If you would connect both of them together, then you could not "Reuse" those components, or even test them cleanly.
It also will encourage you to add more manipulation and business logic inside validation, and slowly slowly will cripple your development.

Comment: Yeah, this is how I am reading it as well.  Going to bring this up in our morning scrum meeting.

Comment: @KungFuMaster Don't be surprised if you hear "if it ain't broke, don't fix it". If this is mature code, cleaning up the design will involve effort that could otherwise have been devoted to stuff that actively bothers users, and it's very likely to introduce new bugs that will actively bother users. Less creditably, they may not like hearing the new(er?) guy telling them their design's goofy, even if they know it is. Be tactful: You may be talking to the guy who thought this was a brilliant idea, implemented it, and hasn't had a single problem with it for five years.

Comment: @KungFuMaster That said, a lot of teams have a list of hidden design horrors that they clean up when time allows, so give it a shot. With any luck, the responsible developer moved on years ago. If you're really lucky, nobody liked him. We used to have a guy who whistled all day and thought that once a feature was finalized, nobody would ever need to read the code again. Little of his code remains.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the approach you want to take:

```
public class ValidationService
{
    private const int MaximumStringLength = 11;

    public bool IsStringValid(string text)
    {
        return IsStringLengthCorrect(text) && IsStringUpper(text);
    }

    public bool IsStringLengthCorrect(string text)
    {
        return text.Length < MaximumStringLength;
    }

    public bool IsStringUpper(string text)
    {
        return text.All(x => char.IsUpper(x));
    }

    public string ValidateStringLength(string text)
    {
        if (IsStringLengthCorrect(text))
        {
            return text;
        }
        else
        {
            return text.Substring(0, MaximumStringLength);
        }
    }

    public string ValidateStringUpper(string text)
    {
        if (IsStringUpper(text))
        {
            return text;
        }
        else
        {
            return text.ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion the validation class, should only check and return if the text is valid.

Anyway with a good naming, order and approach, you can provide methods to return valid inputs.

Comment: The code I pasted in was just something i wrote real quick to demonstrate.  I do agree with "In my opinion the validation class, should only check and return if the text is valid.", makes good sense to me.